# Why is this condition batch flow included in the infinite loop in the spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I made a code maliciously to check how the batch flow works.

```java
@Bean
public Step conditionalJobStep1() {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                            .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                                log.info(">>>>> This is stepNextConditionalJob Step1");
                                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                            }).build();
}

@Bean
public Step conditionalJobStep2() {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("conditionalJobStep2")
                            .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                                log.info(">>>>> This is stepNextConditionalJob Step2");
                                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                            }).build();
}

@Bean
public Step conditionalJobStep3() {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("conditionalJobStep3")
                            .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                                log.info(">>>>> This is stepNextConditionalJob Step3");
                                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                            }).build();
}
```

Here is Steps and tasklets.

```java
@Bean
public Job stepNextConditionalJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("stepNextConditionalJob")
                        .start(conditionalJobStep1())
                            .on("FAILED")
                            .to(conditionalJobStep3())
                            .on("*")
                            .end()
                        .from(conditionalJobStep1())
                            .on("*")
                            .to(conditionalJobStep3())
                            .next(conditionalJobStep2())
                            .on("*")
                            .to(conditionalJobStep1())
                            .on("*")
                            .end()
                        .end()
                            .build();
}
```

above code results 1->3->2->1->3->2->1->..... inf.
I thought What makes this flow.

My Think : Step1 is not FAILED, So start(1) -> to(1) & from(1) -> (3) -> (2) -> to(1) & from(1) -> (3) -> (2) -> ...

but when i modified just 2 numbers like this job(The code that changed only Step2 and Step3 from the previous code after from(step1)) results just 1->2->3->Job end.

```java
@Bean
public Job stepNextConditionalJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("stepNextConditionalJob")
                        .start(conditionalJobStep1())
                            .on("FAILED")
                            .to(conditionalJobStep3())
                            .on("*")
                            .end()
                        .from(conditionalJobStep1())
                            .on("*")
                            .to(conditionalJobStep2())
                            .next(conditionalJobStep3())
                            .on("*")
                            .to(conditionalJobStep1())
                            .on("*")
                            .end()
                        .end()
                            .build();
}
```

Many of own experiments are related to "to" right after the "start".

I don't know why it works like this.

What makes this difference ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring batch conditional flow creates infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209468/spring-batch-conditional-flow-creates-infinite-loop)

Comment: No, I already know that process.
I just changed the order of the two same steps, but I'm asking because I'm curious about the end of the normal job and the infinite process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flow does not define an outcome from step2 on `*`. You have:

```
.to(conditionalJobStep3())
.on("*")
.end()
```

and

```
.to(conditionalJobStep1())
.on("*")
.end()
```

but no such construct for step2. The only outcome you have defined for step 2 is:

```
.next(conditionalJobStep2())
.on("*")
.to(conditionalJobStep1())
```

Which means regardless of step2's exit code , go to `conditionalJobStep1`. That's why you see `1->3->2->1->3->2->1->...`.

> I don't know why it works like this. What makes this difference ?

It works when you flip step2 with step3 because you have defined an outcome on "*" for step3: `.to(conditionalJobStep3()).on("*").end()`.

I recommend using the following syntax to define all outcomes for each step:

```
 jobBuilderFactory.get("stepNextConditionalJob")
   .from(stepA).on(ExitCode1).to(StepB)
   .from(stepA).on(ExitCode2).to(StepC)
   .from(stepA).on("*").end()
   ...
   .from(stepX).on(ExitCode1).to(StepY)
   .from(stepX).on(ExitCode1).to(StepZ)
   .from(stepX).on("*").end()
 .build()
```

This is more explicit and less prone to forgetting outgoing transitions.

Comment: Can I understand that your recommendation is to (start) the job and divide the case into details with the (from~on~to)?(I ask because I don't see the start that I usually use to run a job.)

Comment: Yes, you can start your flow definition with `jobBuilderFactory.get("stepNextConditionalJob").from(stepA)...` and not `jobBuilderFactory.get("stepNextConditionalJob").start(stepA)..`. Both syntaxes are equivalent if the flow is correctly defined. I recommend the one in the answer because it is more explicit and less prone to forgetting transitions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to you, I totally understood!